# 200 new lines in elements_sites per entry

Tags: database, craft4

I noticed that the ID number of my entries has increased to almost 50.000, but I have around 1.000 entries and 2.000 files. I understand that other things like categories also affect that number, but it still seems high.

I looked at the database and found that whenever I add an entry, around 200 additional lines are created in craft_elements_sites. All have slug and uri set to NULL, except between maybe one and five that have the entry’s uri and slug. From what I can see, I think it has something to do with matrix fields, but it also looks like temp or drafts since the same uri is repeated and the timestamps are identical.

Can someone explain what’s happening? And do I need to do something about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone explain what’s happening?

Let's assume we're talking about Craft 4 and not Craft 3.

Native Craft elements include:

- Entries
- Categories
- Tags
- Assets
- Globals
- Matrix Blocks (one element per block)
- Users
- Addresses

Plugins can also add their own elements. Super Table and Neo are similar to Matrix in that it’s one element per block.

It's pretty easy for a single entry to create 200 elements depending on the information architecture and plugins installed.

If it’s a multi-site installation, then you have X elements per entry times Y number of sites the entry has to be propagated to.

Craft’s revisions and drafts are also elements (like entries), so when Craft creates a revision when you’re editing an entry, that’s another element multiplier.

> And do I need to do something about it?

Nah. :)